# Matlab, index from starting location to last index

Tags: matlab, indexing

Say you have an array, data, of unknown length.  Is there a shorter method to get elements form a starting index to the end than

```
subdata = data(2:length(data))
```

Comment: Basically, I am hoping there is an indexing notation for this (like : for all)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`end`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85564) notation to indicate the last element. `data(2:end)` returns a vector containing elements in the vector `data` from element 2 to the last element. Or if `data` is a character array, it returns the second character all the way to the last character. And `data(end)` returns the last element.

This can be done with matrices too, i.e. `data(2:end,5:end)`. Additionally you can use it as an operand, i.e. `data(2:end-1)` , `data(2:end/2)`.

In this context, `end` serves a different purpose from its use at the end of functions/loops/switches.